# AWS send bulk email error with message - "Domain contains dot-dot"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

I am trying to send a large chunk emails and got error with message "Domain contains dot-dot".
Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

```
 #0 /var/www/vhosts/domainame.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-    php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php(76): Aws\Common\Exception\NamespaceExceptionFactory->createException('Aws\\Ses\\Excepti...', Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response), Array)

#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/ExceptionListener.php(55): Aws\Common\Exception\NamespaceExceptionFactory->fromResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response))

#2 [internal function]: Aws\Common\Exception\ExceptionListener->onRequestError(Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error', Object(Symfony\Compone in /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Exception/CommandTransferException.php on line 25

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Service\Exception\CommandTransferException' with message 'Errors during multi transfer
(Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException) /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php line 91

Domain contains dot-dot
```

Answer (score 0):

Domain name of some mail address contains more then one dot sign (.) literally.
eg. Alan@stackoverflow..com

Reference:

1.
https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/diff/mail/src/oldtest/java/javax/mail/internet/addrlist?rev1=61&rev2=62

2. https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.java?rev=557